# How to eliminate delimiters(" ") in .txt file?

Tags: csv, delimiter

I am working with tsv (tab separated values) files. I have used cut command to extract particular columns and store it in a text file as follows-

```
cut -f 6,14-17 test.tsv > outfile.txt
```

**I am getting the following sample output:**

```
"a"  "b"  "c"

"d"  "e"  "f"

"g" "h" "i"
```

**However, the expected output is -**

```
a  b  c

d  e  f

g  h  i
```

Is there a command to delete those quotes or delimiters?

Comment: What environment are you working in. What have you tried so far

Comment: Are you trying to accomplish this all from the command line?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to accomplish this from the command line. But I am also open to other ideas! However, command line would be preferable!

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you read the file line by line and do  `String#replace(...)`:

## Example:

```
String tt = "\"a\" \"b\" \"c\"";
tt = tt.replace("\"", "");

System.out.println(tt);
```

or use lambdas if java8

Answer (score 0):

Use [sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html)

```
cut -f 6,14-17 test.tsv | sed 's/"//g' > outfile.txt
```

Basically, replace all occurences of `"` by nothing.